# How do I get a string from an awt textField?

Tags: java, awt

I'm wanting to get a string print from a textField so I can print it to the screen, how do I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can be answered by consulting the available [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.getText()` method to obtain it. Simply declare a string-type/declare as it is used and the resulting output will be a string type.

---

```
String data = "Username: "+userInput.getText();
data +=", Password: "+passInput.getText();

System.out.println("Username Entered: "+userInput.getText()+" Password: "+passInput.getText());
enter code here

  statusLabel.setText(data);
```